# How to find cities with similar weather conditions

Tags: online-resources, weather-and-climate

I plan to travel to cities where I can experience weather cycles that I am currently used to. How can one find cities in different countries that have the same weather cycles ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Is this a trick question? Just go directly east or west, and you'll always be at the same latitude.  Use a compass or look at a map if it makes it easier.  What do you want to know?

Comment: This won't work well for people who live in Scandinavia.

Comment: @choster How did you do this 'copy the table into a spreadsheet and sort by latitude' on google maps ? I am trying to find cities which are on the same latitude as Darwin, Australia and am unable to point exactly the other city locations on the same latitude

Comment: Shouldn't your question be "How to find cities with similar weather conditions?" As said, latitude has almost nothing to do with the weather.

Comment: @andra I think thats a better way to ask it. Done.

Comment: Don't know will it help you or not - [Weather Online](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/) has average monthly data for most of the cities in the world. You can also check [Weather Base](http://www.weatherbase.com/). It has a service of searcing cities by average temperature

Comment: @happybuddha From my browser, I select all the text in the table and copy it to the clipboard. I open Excel 2010 and paste in the results. I do this a lot with HTML tables.

Comment: Here in Ecuador, latitude is pretty much always 0. Altitude is everything though. We have 20+ degrees difference within a few hours of driving, as changes in humidity levels.

Answer (score 7):

This might be what you're looking for. You just enter the name of a city and it searches for cities with similar weather records. http://mikemcbrearty.com/climate/

Comment: Amazing find--.

Answer (score 6):

The [Köppen climate classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification) seems like a good starting point. It might not be as fine-grained as you'd like but the various categories seem to line up with the way we experience climate better than looking at quantitative variables like temperature or precipitation.

Answer (score 2):

I will update this answer if someone finds an online resource of

- [temperature(average/min/max)](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/hi-res-temperature-map-forecast-io/)
- humidity
- sunshine/rain ratio
- wind conditions

but currently you need them out themselves and there is no shortcut.
See, New York City and Madrid are on the same latitude, but Madrid is much warmer and has no blizzards at all. It really depends on many factors than latitude alone: Is the city flat or residing in a mountain range ? Is it coastal (less temperature range) or continental ? If coastal, is it in vicinity of a stream (warm/cold) ? Are there humid winds or is it dry ? Is it protected from wind or has it a strong breeze ? What is the elevation of the city ?

Even the linked temperature map is only a hint because average temperature does tell nothing about the min/max range. Continental deserts are really hot during the day, but could have freezing temperatures at night, giving a much lower average than expected. Cities build from stone with small ways and no green could be much hotter than a lush city with waterways and white painted wood houses under the same condition.

Comment: This sounds more like an extended comment than an actual answer.

Comment: @Relaxed: As said, I would update it. But +1 for bringing up Köppen-Geiger classification.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see location on a continent is much more important than latitude. Further more influences like golf streams and regular winds and wind patterns.
And whether you live in mountains or there are mountains between important weather features and you.

As someone living on the west coast of continental Europe, I find most of the coastal areas of Western Europe feel like home, weather wise.
I have been on the west coast of Canada, and had the feeling the weather there was not that far different either. 
And much of the New Zealand west coast, as well as that of Tasmania felt like near enough that I would happily settle there, as I know the weather.

As soon as I travel inland I will get warmer summers and colder winters, but in Europe less so than in the USA or the eastern parts of Russia.

On the other hand, if you are from a subtropical coastal location, only subtropical coastal locations will feel at home.

So I think it is not a case of entering your home location into a website and getting a handy answer with all locations with like weather. Weather depends on so many local conditions.

It might be best to start with looking at a map, locating all features that make your local weather. (For instance, most of continental USA has Polar influences in winter, Golf of Mexico influences in summer. If you live near a west coast but with mountains between you and the ocean, you will be in a rain shadow.